# Kotlin, android

Tags: android, kotlin

**MainActivity.kt**
I have successfully moved my app to background using MoveTaskToBack (true)
I am trying to get it back to show I having difficulty

I had even included the person for task reorder in kotlin manifest, still am having problems this is my code same below.
``
// Declaring and initializing the

```
    // TextView from the layout file 

    val mTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view) 

      

    // Getting the instance of ActivityManager 

    val mActivityManager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager 

      

    // Getting the tasks in the form of a list 

    val mRecentTasks: List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> = Objects.requireNonNull(mActivityManager).getRunningTasks(Int.MAX_VALUE) 



    var mString = ""



    // Creating a string of each index of the list 

    for (i in mRecentTasks.indices){
```

if(mRecentTasks[i].baseActivity?.toShortString() .indexOf("com.example.myassisant") > -1) {
mActivityManager.moveTaskToFront( mRecentTasks[i].get(i).id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME)
}

```
    }
```

Comment: Where does this code even reside, since your task has been put away? Is this in a service or broadcast receiver? To get your task back, start an Activity with matching Intent. Your Activity should have a task affinity that allows it to resume from where it was before. Also, it would be nice if you could put a useful title for your question so it can be useful for future searchers. The question title is not for putting vague tag words.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to be easier for the community to help you.

Comment: @Hector sorry for those bad English, punctuations and other discomforts I may have caused, it wasn't deliberately done